# Pig : Adding new column to existing inner Tuple in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I want to add new column to existing tuple column in Pig.

Example:Input Schema:

```
name: chararray,
attribute_list: {innertuple: (height: int,length: int,size: chararray)}
```

Output Schema:
Using generate statement I want to add new column in tuple which will hold the same value as length but with some other name.

```
name: chararray,
attribute_list: {innertuple: (height: int,length: int,size: chararray, len : int)}
```

I tried below approach but its not working:

```
op = Foreach input_data generate
name,
attribute_list as attr : {(
height,
length,
size,
length as len)};
```

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i would suggest you to go through pig documents- http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/start.html

Comment: @RahulSharma Though this advice is not bad, I would encourage you to at least hint at which part of the documentation is relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Add a rank to each row, flatten attribute_list bag then recreate bag with additional columns.

```
--Rank input_schema(ip) using rank function:

ranked= rank ip;

-- flatten each value of bag.tuple to row level  
a= foreach ranked generate rank_ip as id, flatten(attribute_list.$0), flatten(attribute_list.$0.length) as len;

b= group a by id;

op= foreach b generate flatten($1.name) as name, $1 as attr;

--The name also will be part of attr bag.
```

**Option 2:**

a. The [DataFu](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.linkedin.datafu/datafu/0.0.8/datafu/pig/bags/BagConcat.java) has a pig udf to concat multiple tuple around bag.
   b. Create UDF BagConcat.

```
define BagConcat datafu.pig.bags.BagConcat();
```

c. Flatten elements:

```
a= foreach ip generate name, flatten(attribute_list.$0), flatten(attribute_list.$0.length) as len;
```

d. Reproject your bag:

```
op= foreach a generate name, BagConcat(height,len,size,len) as attr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = LOAD 'PATH' USING PigStorage() AS (ID:INT);
B = FOREACH sourcenew GENERATE *, null as len:int;
```

You can also give any integer value in place of null.